# How to use global prefix command key in define mode-map key binding?

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, prefix-keys

I have a global prefix command key define like following:

```
(unless (boundp 'help-document-map)
  (define-prefix-command 'help-document-map))
;; (define-key my-programming-prefix-k (kbd "h") 'help-document-map)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-h d") 'help-document-map)
```

And then I want to use it in following mode-map defining keys.

```
(eval-after-load "helm-cscope"
  '(progn
     (define-key helm-cscope-mode-map (kbd "M-t") 'helm-cscope-find-symbol)
     (define-key helm-cscope-mode-map (kbd "M-r") 'helm-cscope-find-global-definition)
     (define-key helm-cscope-mode-map (kbd "M-g M-c") 'helm-cscope-find-called-function)
     (define-key helm-cscope-mode-map (kbd "M-g M-p") 'helm-cscope-find-calling-this-funtcion)
     (define-key helm-cscope-mode-map (kbd "M-s") 'helm-cscope-select)))
```

So how do I define this key binding?

Comment: It's really hard to know what's being asked here. Would you mind rewording?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is for <kbd>C-h d</kbd> to act as a prefix to a map dependent on the current mode.

There are a couple of solutions to this. One solution I have seen used in a couple of modes is to prefix each of the `kbd` calls with say `help-document-prefix`.

```
(defvar helm-document-prefix "C-h d")
(eval-after-load "helm-cscope"
  '(progn
     (define-key helm-cscope-mode-map 
                 (kbd (concat help-document-prefix " M-t")) 
                 'helm-cscope-find-symbol)))
```

This approach will enable <kbd>C-h d M-t</kbd> when `helm-cscope-mode-map` is active.

Another approach would be to set these bindings using `local-set-key` but inside of the mode hook. That would do a better job of respecting the `help-document-prefix` variable changing, as the binding would update every time the mode was enabled.

I don't know if there is a way to use a prefix map to dispatch to a function, which in turn dispatches to a keymap. It is possible to inherit from another keymap, but I don't know as that would help here.

Comment: I add a hook like this: (add-hook 'helm-cscope-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (local-set-key (kbd (concat my-prog-help-document-map " M-t")) 'helm-cscope-find-symbol)))  . But it report error: wrong type argument: characterp, keymap.

Comment: As you said, I did a search in GitHub code, and try to find some examples with (kbd (concat ...)). Found an example https://github.com/schnecki/dot-emacs.d/blob/9e792963a8dc52f388d4c1cacde7b387337cce9c/24/packages_configs/multiple_cursors_config.el