# make local map bindings available through a global prefix

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, prefix-keys

I am trying to set up something like Spacemacs, but fully under my control.  I have already created a tree of my own keymaps with global commands, and it is available on `M-SPC`.  But now I'd like to also make available local bindings for major modes, those that typically start with `C-c`, through the same prefix `M-SPC`, but *without* the `C-c`.

Clearly I cannot just get the part of the local map after `C-c` and graft it onto my `M-SPC` tree - it would have to be a function that looks up the binding on the fly.  But how to read the key sequence? `read-key-sequence` only works on "active" maps according to the doc - indeed it has to because it has no keymap argument.  But the keymap I need to consult when reading the keys is *not* active, it is the *`sub`*-keymap of the local map after `C-c`.  So I seem to be stuck.

Comment: Please add an example, including not only the things you *do* want, but also things you want to *avoid* in the process (such as binding keys you *don't want* to bind).  Make the example sufficient to demonstrate all the requirements.  As it stands, I think your question is difficult to understand.

Comment: @phils : right now, I have a bunch of *global* bindings starting with `M-SPC`.  Now, the *local* map in C mode, for example , has a binding of `C-c C-n` to `c-forward-conditional`.  I would like to bind `M-SPC C-n` to `c-forward-conditional` in C mode only; and not only that, but also all the parallel bindings, such as `M-SPC C-p` to `c-backward-conditional`, in a systematic way [1].  And similarly for other major modes I use.  Is that more clear?

Comment: in a systematic way: ie. without coding each one by hand.  What I want to avoid is that those mode-specific bindings stick around when I leave that particular major mode.

Comment: So are you saying you want *every* local binding under the `C-c` prefix (and only that prefix) to also be available under the `M-SPC` prefix?  (And without losing the global bindings you already have under `M-SPC`).

Comment: That sounds about right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the clarifications to the question, something like this might do the trick?

```el
(defvar my-leader-map (make-sparse-keymap)
  "Prefix binding for custom things.")

(global-set-key (kbd "M-SPC") my-leader-map)

;; My global bindings go here.  E.g.:
(define-key my-leader-map (kbd "C-b") 'other-window)
;; etc...

;; Default binding.
(define-key my-leader-map [t] 'my-leader-map-default)

(defun my-leader-map-default ()
  "Use the binding under the C-c prefix of `current-local-map'."
  (interactive)
  (let ((prefix (lookup-key (current-local-map) (kbd "C-c"))))
    (when (keymapp prefix)
      (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
        (set-keymap-parent map prefix)
        (define-key map [t] 'undefined)
        (set-transient-map map)
        (push last-command-event unread-command-events)))))
```

---

Or perhaps this, which would make the bindings more discoverable:

```el
(defvar my-leader-map (make-sparse-keymap)
  "Prefix binding for custom things.")

(global-set-key (kbd "M-SPC") my-leader-map)

;; My global bindings go here.  E.g.:
(define-key my-leader-map (kbd "C-b") 'other-window)
;; etc...

(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook #'my-leader-map-set-local)

(defun my-leader-map-set-local ()
  "Set `current-local-map' to include C-c bindings under `my-leader-map'."
  (when (current-local-map)
    (let ((prefix (lookup-key (current-local-map) (kbd "C-c"))))
      (when (keymapp prefix)
        (use-local-map
         (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
           (set-keymap-parent map (current-local-map))
           (define-key map (kbd "M-SPC")
                       (make-composed-keymap my-leader-map prefix))
           map))))))
```

You might cache and re-use the latter maps on a per-major-mode basis.

---

Edit: One more... this somewhere between the others, functionality-wise: <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>M-SPC</kbd><kbd><foo></kbd> will work for local-map bindings, but <kbd>M-SPC</kbd><kbd>C-h</kbd> will only show your custom bindings.

Caveat: I'm not 100% certain that `(lookup-key prefix (vector last-input-event))` is valid for all situations.

```el
(defvar my-leader-map (make-sparse-keymap)
  "Prefix binding for custom things.")

(global-set-key (kbd "M-SPC") my-leader-map)

;; My global bindings go here.  E.g.:
(define-key my-leader-map (kbd "C-b") 'other-window)
;; etc...

(define-key my-leader-map [t]
  `(menu-item "" nil :filter ,#'my-leader-map-default-filter))

(defun my-leader-map-default-filter (_cmd)
  "Use the binding under the C-c prefix of `current-local-map'."
  (let ((prefix (lookup-key (current-local-map) (kbd "C-c"))))
    (when (keymapp prefix)
      (lookup-key prefix (vector last-input-event)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

- Using [general.el](https://github.com/noctuid/general.el), you can bind a key under `SPC` to a [`general-simulate-key`](https://github.com/noctuid/general.el/blob/master/README.org#simulating-keypresses) call:

```
(general-def
  "SPC c" (general-simulate-key "C-c"))
```

Since `C-c` and `C-x` bindings will have conflicts if merged (like `C-c @` and `C-x @`), this is probably the most doable method.

- There is a builtin function, `describe-buffer-bindings`, that tells you which keys are bound to what in the current buffer, and it accepts a `prefix` as an argument, but it is a C function that inserts something like this into the current buffer:

```
(describe-buffer-bindings (current-buffer) (kbd "C-c")) ; in an Elisp buffer
```

```
`magit-file-mode' Minor Mode Bindings Starting With C-c:
key             binding
---             -------

C-c ESC         Prefix Command

C-c M-g         magit-file-dispatch


`magit-file-mode' Minor Mode Bindings Starting With C-c:
key             binding
---             -------

C-c ESC         Prefix Command


`hs-minor-mode' Minor Mode Bindings Starting With C-c:
key             binding
---             -------

C-c @           Prefix Command

C-c @ C-a       hs-show-all
C-c @ C-c       hs-toggle-hiding
C-c @ C-d       hs-hide-block
C-c @ C-e       hs-toggle-hiding
C-c @ C-h       hs-hide-block
C-c @ C-l       hs-hide-level
C-c @ C-s       hs-show-block
C-c @ C-t       hs-hide-all
C-c @ ESC       Prefix Command

C-c @ C-M-h     hs-hide-all
C-c @ C-M-s     hs-show-all


`nameless-mode' Minor Mode Bindings Starting With C-c:
key             binding
---             -------

C-c C--         nameless-insert-name


Global Bindings Starting With C-c:
key             binding
---             -------

C-c c           org-capture
```

So there doesn't seem to be a proper way to get bindings that you can use to get a raw keymap.

Comment: Please consider providing a link to general.el.

Comment: The problem is not to get the bindings: that can be done with `map-keymap`, for example. The main problem is exactly as I stated in the title: how to make these local bindings, once discovered/computed, available under the global prefix.

Comment: The closest existing question: [https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/707/how-to-use-global-prefix-command-key-in-define-mode-map-keybinding?rq=1]

Answer (score 0):

I am a fool.  There was never a problem to start with.  Since bindings from active keymaps (including the global and local) are merged, all that is necessary is to add the desired bindings, starting with `M-SPC`, to each mode keymap where I want it to happen.  This is much simpler and also a bit safer than the proposal by @phils because it keeps the effect isolated to an explicitly chosen handful of mode keymaps.

Nonetheless I'm acking @phils answer because I think it is correct.